# Computing Predecessor and Successor

Tags: algorithm, conditional-statements

I come across an interesting question and I want to discuss it in order to see how it will be approached by different people:

Let `n` be a natural number, the task is to implement a function `f` so that

```
f(n) = n + 1 if 2 divides n
f(n) = n - 1 if 2 does not divide n
```

**Condition:** The implementation must not use conditional constructs

---

My Answer is `f(n) = n xor 1`

Comment: `I [came] across an interesting question` `the task is` `My [solution] is` `I want to discuss [the problem]` you present an approach based on the prevalent binary representation of integral numbers, [Keyvan](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41403061/3789665) one based on arithmetic operators. Please point out _what_ you want discussed. If possible, ask a question possible to answer.

Comment: I want to discuss different ways for solving the problem. Did you see my approach, @Keiwan ´s approach. Do you have any idea how to solve it differently?

Comment: `[What are ideas] how to solve it differently?`Don't comment comments asking for additional information or clarification: edit your post. `Did you see my approach, @Keiwan ´s approach` How do you read `you present an approach based on the prevalent binary representation of integral numbers, Keyvan one based on arithmetic operators`? How could I describe both without having seen them?

Comment: (And yes, I did get [Keiwan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6214222/keiwan)'s name wrong. (Sorry))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
f(n) = n + 1 - 2 * (n % 2)
```

because

`(n % 2) == 0` if 2 divides `n` and therefore `f(n) = n + 1 - 0` and

`(n % 2) == 1` if 2 does not divide `n` and therefore `f(n) = n + 1 - 2 = n - 1`